# convert foreach to LINQ statement using where

Tags: c#, linq, collections

How to rewrite given foreach loop using LINQ where statemetn?

```
List<ItemData> dbItems = _dataService.GetAllItems();
List<ItemModel> modeList = new List<ItemModel>();
foreach (ItemData p in dbItems )
{
    ItemModel m = Mapper.ItemDataToModelMap(p);
    modeList.Add(m);
}
```

I have tried this, but this gives error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'...

```
 var modeList= from m in dbItems 
     select new {item = Mapper.ItemDataToModelMap(m)     
 };
```

Edit:
The method that uses this should return IEnumerable, so this is the error cause. I should not change return type, instaed the code and anonymous type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have a `List<ItemModel>` as a result try this:

```
var modeList = dbItems
    .Select(m => Mapper.ItemDatatoModelMap(m))
    .ToList();
```

Using query notation:

```
var modeList = (from m in dbItems select Mapper.ItemDataToModelMap(m))
    .ToList();
```

`new { ... }` notation creates an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), while you need a `List<T>` with a particular type - `ItemModel`.

Also note, that there is nothing wrong syntactically with:

```
var modeList= from m in dbItems 
    select new {item = Mapper.ItemDataToModelMap(m)};
```

But your description of the error is not clear. You're either not using `var` as you've presented (but `List<ItemModel>`), or doing something else with `modeList` that leads to a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Bit pre coffee here, but is this what you are looking for:

```
var modeList= from m in dbItems 
     select Mapper.ItemDataToModelMap(m);
```