# convert foreach to linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

I have the following code which transforms a List of `myCar` objects to an Array of Car objects from a third-party web service so I can then pass the cars to the 3rd party web service:

```
var cars = new Car[myCars.Count];
var count = 0;
foreach (var myCar in myCars)
{
   cars[count] = new Car
   {
      Id = myCar.Id,
      Manufacturer = myCar.Manufacturer,
      Model = myCar.Model
   };
   count++;
}
return cars;
```

Note as my myCar object has a number of other features other than the three the 3rd Party web service has I cant do something simple such as:

```
MyClass[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

The code is working as expected but I am wondering is there something in Linq such as a Select expression which would make this better and take less code?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974013/convert-foreach-to-linq-statement-using-where) should help get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a list's property using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691123/change-a-lists-property-using-linq)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var cars = myCars.Select(myCar => new Car
{
    Id = myCar.Id,
    Manufacturer = myCar.Manufacturer,
    Model = myCar.Model
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: What is not recommended?

Comment: Yeah, this is just creating a new anonymous type. This is fine (?)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama do you see any ForEach here?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I'm not seeing the relevance of that article to this answer.  This is a perfectly legitimate use of `Select` and `ToArray`.

Comment: @sircodesalot this is not creating an anonymous type. It's creating an IEnumerable of Car that is iterated over by the ToArray extension method to produce an array of Car.

Comment: @JeremyCook ah right. Even more reason this example is fine.

Comment: So I totally put my foot in my mouth here. Sorry for it, this is valid and ignore my ramblings. I was recently reading about the immutable nature of linq and messed up my understanding of the article. Sorry all...

Answer (score 3):

The `Select` linq method lets you transform one object into another:

```
var cars = myCars.Select( c => new Car { id = c.Id, Manufacturer = c.Manufacturer, Model = c.Model } ).ToArray()
```

I think that will do it.